# Python: Removing Duplicates based on unique combination of two features and a condition on 3rd feature

Tags: python, database, algorithm, pandas, merge

The problem to solve is the following:
I have two datasets that I want to merge into one. Datasets do not have common key column. I would like to exclude duplicates based on unique combinations of column 1 and column 2 and similarity of the column 3. By similarity I mean that values of Column 3 in Dataset A are only slightly greater\less than in Dataset B, e.g. for value 20, values from range [18,22] are acceptable. An example will make it more clear:

Dataset A:

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
1 A   | A    | 10   |
2 B   | A    | 20   |
3 A   | B    | 10   |
4 B   | B    | 20   |
```

Dataset B:

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
1 A   | A    | 10   |
2 B   | A    | 21   |
3 A   | B    | 100  |
```

- Row 1 is exactly the same in both datasets, so I want to include only one row in my final dataset.
- Columns 1 and 2 are exactly the same in row 2. However, the value in column 3 is  **slightly**  different: 20 vs 21. I want to treat these rows as duplicates and include only one row, e.g. from dataset A
- Columns 1 and 2 are exactly the same in row 3. However, the value in column 3 is  **extremely**  different: 10 vs 100. I would like to include both rows in my final dataset.
- Row 4 in dataset A is not present in dataset B, so I would like to include it into my final dataset.

Expected output:

```
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
1 A   | A    | 10   |
2 B   | A    | 20   |
3 A   | B    | 10   |
4 A   | B    | 100  |
5 B   | B    | 20   |
```

Is there method with computational complexity lower than O(n^2) [checking each row with each row] ?

Comment: Do you have a mathemical definition of "slightly" within 5%? or within +/- three units?  Something more concrete and programmable over "slightly".  Thanks.

Comment: Adding to @ScottBoston's question, most likely definitions of 'slightly' probably aren't transitive. What should happen when rows k & m and rows m & n are slightly different, but rows k & n are extremely different?

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to create a mapping of `(Col1, Col2) -> Col3` of Dataset A. Each row in B can then look in the mapping to see which `Col3` values exist of Dataset A with the same `Col1` and `Col2` values.

Pseudocode as I'm not familiair with the `pandas` library:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def is_close(a, b):
    return abs(a-b) < some_value

d = defaultdict(list)
for col1, col2, col3 in A:
    d[(col1, col2)].append(col3)

for col1, col2, col3 in B:
    if not any(is_close(col3, x) for x in d[(col1, col2)]):
        add_to_result(col1, col2, col3)
```

defaultdict is required as there are rows in A with the same value for `col1` and `col2`. This should be faster as creating the mapping is `O(n)` and looping over each element in B should only check for elements in A with the same `col1` and `col2` values.